# Availability metric chart for Azure storage account going to 0 but alert shown as 100%

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an alert configured on Azure storage account which should get fired whenever the availability goes below 100%. This alert has never fired till now. However, in the availability metric chart shown at azure for past hour (attached below), the availability is shown to go below 100 multiple times. It seems that the availability oscillates between 100 and 0.

[image]

However, if I increase the time range to 24 hours, the availability is shown to be at 100 always (which it should be, because the alert never went off). The image of the same is attached below.
[image]

Can anyone please explain the first availability chart?

Comment: It is possible the system is in sleep/suspend if there is no activity.

Comment: I had asked a separate question regarding this and it was answered that the availability is considered 100% if no incoming requests are there. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262817/availability-of-azure-storage-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question. Metrics in Azure Portal has been improved. In the improved behavior, you will see a dotted line at 100% if there is no incoming traffic. We suggest you to look at Transactions metrics to understand total incoming traffic.
[image]

Based on the post date, I believe you were looking at old behavior before the improvement. If there is no incoming request in that minute, you see 0% in minutely chart, instead of 100%. Same applies to hourly chart.

Please check out the new Metrics in Azure Portal and let me know if you still see unexpected 0%.